# Android Studio slow performance

Tags: performance, android-studio, lag

I've updated Android Studio to version 2.3 yesterday and since after I'm experiencing a slow performance, it was working fine before, though slow when gradle building, but now it taking 100% of processors resources.

What is the requirements for Android Studio to run smoothly?

**My computer runs Windows 7 x64,  i7 core, with 8 cores, 10Gb of RAM**

[image: Here is a screenshot]

Comment: And here I was thinking an upgrade from my current 6GB RAM to 8GB RAM would solve my problems.

Comment: Doing this could solve your problem if you have fast processors

Comment: If found out mine had 1.6GHz (133 MHz each core). Not fast enough

Comment: I have a 2.70GHz processor.I guess that'd be enough then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was solved by invalidating cache. Somebody, I don't remember where, suggested me that as it was an update from a lower version, I should try invalidating the cache then restart.

Here is the step:

**FILE > INVALIDATE CACHES / RESTART**

Now it runs smoothly like before.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go with three easy steps to get Android Studio Fast :

**Step 1 : Open `gradle.properties` file of your app and add in two lines as follows...**

```
org.gradle.daemon=true  
org.gradle.parallel=true
```

**Step 2 : File —> Settings —> Compiler ——> Command-line-Options (enter –offline) File —-> Settings —–> Compiler ——> ——> Enable Configure on Demand**

Description : Click `File` visible at the left most corner of your Android Studio and then select `Settings` under it.  In the `Settings` screen search for `Compiler` and here you should find `Command-Line-Options`, where you need to enter `–offline`.  At the bottom most you will also have to enable the option `Configure On Demand`.

**Step 3 : File —-> Settings —–> Gradle —–> Enable Offline work**

Description : Under the `Settings` screen, search for `Gradle` and `Enable Offline Work` option in it.

Answer (score 3):

**To run Android environment on low configuration machine.**

1. Close the unnecessary web tabs in browser
2. For Antivirus users, exclude the build folder which is auto generated
3. Android studio have **1.2 GB default heap can decrease to 512 MB**

> Help > Edit custom VM options

```
studio.vmoptions
 -Xmx512m
```

Layouts performance will be speed up

4. For Gradle one of the core component in Android studio Make sure
   like right now **3.0beta** is latest one

**Below tips can affect the code quality so please use with cautions:**

1. Studio contain **Power safe Mode** when turned on it will close background operations that lint , code completions and so on.
2. You can run manually lint check when needed `./gradlew lint`
3. Most of are using **Android emulators** on average it **consume 2 GB RAM** so if possible use actual Android device these will reduce your resource load on your computer. Alternatively you can reduce the RAM of the emulator and it will automatically reduce the virtual memory consumption on your computer. you can find this in virtual device configuration and advance setting.
4. **Gradle offline mode** is a feature for bandwidth limited users to **disable** the downloading of build dependencies. It will reduce the background operation that will help to increase the performance of Android studio.
5. Android studio offers an optimization to **compile multiple modules** in parallel. On low RAM machines this feature will likely have a **negative impact** on the performance. You can disable it in the **compiler settings dialog**.

Answer (score 2):

A very easy way to improve performance in Android Studio regardless of any machine is to disable a bunch of plugins.

Jake Wharton lists a few plugins that may be safe to disable. I personally saw a night and day improvement by following his directions.

Here is the link to the comment: 
https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/7sxhig/android_studio_slower_when_using_kotlin/dt88pgn

Answer (score 1):

My solution is: WORK OFFLINE.
It happened to me always, every time I tried to launch project.
Finally (and by pure chance), I shut down my Antivirus and my Firewall and the performance increased 10 times.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was due to GPU. My computer has 2 GPUs one is intel's integrated GPU which is for ordinary works, and other one is NVIDIA GPU which is for Games and Other more sophisticated works.

Intel GPU was assigned to Android Studio by default, I changed it.
Right Click on Desktop/ Nvidia Control Panel/
3D settings/Manage 3D settings (from the right panel)
Then 
Program settings/Choose NVIDIA for android studio